# How is the soundex code for burroughs is B622 instead of B620?

Tags: algorithm

[Steps of Soundex Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

[Site For Checking Soundex code](https://www.functions-online.com/soundex.html)

> If two or more letters with the same number are adjacent in the original name (before step 1), only retain the first letter; also **two letters with the same number separated by 'h' or 'w' are coded as a single number**, whereas such letters separated by a vowel are coded twice. This rule also applies to the first letter.

Soundex Algo

Dropping vowels and letter 'h' and 'w' `Burroughs`  will convert to its numeric form as `B6622`  Applying adjacent same number rule will give code `B62` .Since we need three numbers we append zero at the end.
So finally code should be B620!??

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is.

Comment: Please formulate a clear question instead of posting a link (that will eventually die). See help center to get how it works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Soundex code for `Burroughs` is **B620**.

Confirmed by manually working through the "alternate" version of the American Soundex algorithm listed on Wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Burroughs:

1. Burrougs
2. 1u66ou22
3. 1u6ou2
4. 162
5. B62
6. B620

Also verified with another soundex calculator.
http://resources.rootsweb.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/soundexconverter

The original Soundex function checker web site you used does seem to be wrong - it is not applying the "h/w" part of the algorithm you highlighted in your question. That web site gives the same value "B622" for "Burroughs" and "Burrouges", which it should not.